# Is it safe to delete the file /etc/hosts.deny?

Tags: denyhosts

I installed *Denyhosts* and then my permanent ip was partially blocked for some reason ("partially" blocked because while I couldn't ssh or ftp, I was able to http into my sites).

I deleted *Denyhosts* and was still blocked so I logged in from another computer with another ip and removed my ip from `/etc/hosts.deny`. Then, I was no longer blocked and ssh'd successfully.

Yet, for some reason I became partially blocked again and had to repeat the process.

### My question

My question can be comprised of the following questions:

1. Why did /etc/hosts.deny not deleted when I did `apt-get purge denyhosts`?
2. Is it safe to fully remove /etc/hosts.deny so that only `iptables` will block ip's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [man page for `hosts.deny`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/hosts.deny) (`man hosts.deny`) explains the order of processing:

> The access control software consults two files. The search stops at the first match:
>
> - Access  will  be  granted when a (daemon,client) pair matches an entry in the /etc/hosts.allow file.
> - Otherwise, access will be denied  when  a  (daemon,client)  pair matches an entry in the /etc/hosts.deny file.
> - Otherwise, access will be granted.

So from this you can see that it is quite safe to delete `/etc/hosts.deny` (and `/etc/hosts.allow`, for that matter).

Now, as to your question regarding the automatic deletion - or not - of `/etc/hosts.deny` when you uninstall `denyhosts`. This file - and its complement `/etc/hosts.allow` - belongs to `tcp_wrappers` so it is not for `denyhosts` to remove it when you uninstall it.